# How to delete queue using boto

Tags: boto, amazon-sqs

I need to delete the queue using boto. I not sure about how to delete a queue. I tried this but it didn't work:

```
queue = conn.create_queue(sqs) #sqs is the queue name
conn.delete_queue(queue)
```

Comment: removed unnecessary content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In boto v2**

```
>>> import boto.sqs
>>> conn=boto.sqs.connect_to_region('ap-southeast-2')
>>> q = conn.create_queue('foo')
>>> q
Queue(https://ap-southeast-2.queue.amazonaws.com/123456789012/foo)
>>> q.__dict__
{'ResponseMetadata': '', 'url': u'https://ap-southeast-2.queue.amazonaws.com/123456789012/foo', 'CreateQueueResponse': '', 'message_class': <class 'boto.sqs.message.Message'>, 'connection': SQSConnection:ap-southeast-2.queue.amazonaws.com, 'RequestId': u'9bfb9b6d-d9b5-5a29-9ea5-d4dbd5e3ef5a', 'CreateQueueResult': '', 'visibility_timeout': None}
>>> conn.delete_queue(q)
True
```

**In boto3**

```
>>> import boto3
>>> client = boto3.client('sqs')
>>> q = client.create_queue(QueueName='foo')
>>> q
{u'QueueUrl': 'https://ap-southeast-2.queue.amazonaws.com/123456789012/foo', 'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': 'f6531b80-4387-57a2-98fa-54364841c158'}}
>>> client.delete_queue(QueueUrl=q['QueueUrl'])
{'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': 'f9d3853c-12f2-598b-ad3c-ca8a1f68754a'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to get the queue --

```
queue = conn.create_queue('myqueue')  // asuming your queue name 'myqueue'
```

Then you can simply delete the queue --

```
conn.delete_queue(queue)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Boto3, use the Queue resource. Here's some code that's part of a larger example on [GitHub](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/40a75de3f87ee5dcc43aae320b878fb199fc463b/python/example_code/sqs/queue_wrapper.py#L115):

```
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')

def remove_queue(queue):
    try:
        queue.delete()
        logger.info("Deleted queue with URL=%s.", queue.url)
    except ClientError as error:
        logger.exception("Couldn't delete queue with URL=%s!", queue.url)
        raise error

queue = sqs.create_queue(QueueName=name, Attributes=attributes)
remove_queue(queue)
```